# Android app to show what apps/processes are currently using data

Tags: android, monitoring, data, bandwidth

What Android app shows, ***in real-time***, what apps and processes are currently transmitting and receiving data?

I am interested in quantity of data being transmitted (not speed).

Recommendations for paid apps are fine, but *gratis* is preferred.

Apps requiring root are acceptable, but please specify if it requires root privileges in your answer.

*Note that Android's integrated data manager sort of does this, but it is really only effective for cumulative data over multiple days.  It doesn't work well for real-time information.*

Comment: Depends on the details you are interested in, one of my [Network Monitoring](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_diagnosis#group_1006) apps should fit. Have not tried any, so I cannot give a recommendation. But my guess is [Network Connections](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antispycell.connmonitor) is your candidate, by [this screenshot](https://lh6.ggpht.com/SzusQjXfLwdwQxDMOcE2zRWgpiD_1lv__L8PiWPyeweETXGNkzhGP4GYs9rVLAY1W4LfjOHFjEPR9InC9cs-gQg) :)

Comment: Anytime! Be welcome to self-answer if it fits :)

Answer (score 1):

Since there was no  answer posted yet, I decided to include it anyway.

Currently the best option of achieving that is using [Network Connections](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antispycell.connmonitor) as Izzy rightly suggested (and I happen to use the same application as well).

This app is user friendly can be installed on non-rooted devices as well.

> After you launch the app, the first thing you will see is the Current
>   Connection tab. This tab tells you the connections that are currently
>   active on your mobile and the apps that are connected to the internet.
>   It also shows the amount of data packets being transferred in **real time**.

[image]

**Key Features**:

- Monitors all internet connections from and to your Android device
- Displays notification when hidden apps are connecting to remote servers
- Displays detailed IP information for each connection - IP address, reverse resolving (PTR), AS number, Abuse RBL data, administrative information, etc.
- Gets detailed info about each app that connects to remote servers and network connections used by it - permissions granted to each captured package and all IP addresses used by it.
- Real-time sort by most active, latest connections or by package name.
- Log and export the captured data.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Bytes Insight](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.bytesinsight&hl=en_US) by Oasis Feng.

Bytes Insight is a very lightweight application about 127kB and uses very little memory in background.

Bytes Insight calculates in real-time, what apps and processes are currently transmitting and receiving data. In other words shows exactly  how many kilobytes are uploaded/downloaded by given processes.

[image: IMG:]

Additionally you can use the Traffic Sensitivity option to fine tune the accuracy at which it measures the data being transmitted. The default setting counts per 10KB:

[image: IMG:]

<sup>Credits: *[Track data usage live with Byte Insights (and images)](https://www.android-user.de/mit-byte-insights-den-datenverbrauch-live-verfolgen/)*</sup>